# Sky a solid object?

Tags: quran, science

Salam,

does the Qur'an describe the sky as a solid object?

In Quran 22:65 Allah says that he withholds the sky from falling. How is this possible when the sky is not a solid roof?

Jkzh in advance, pls give sincere answers

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't mean here the "atmosphere" but the universe (or lower heaven, the one where the solar system is located in).

The "pieces of the sky" here probably means the meteorites in space. (In the Quran, sky can both mean atmosphere and universe). Allah can control gravity (see the verses where He says He sent down water from the sky, and we know today that effectively the Earth's water came from meteorites so from space), so He is able to send down pieces of the sky (pieces of the universe) on humans.

If it’s not meteorites, then maybe it is the 7 heavens falling on us. Because in sueah Ar-Raad 2:

> "Allah is He Who raised the heavens without any pillars that ye can see;"

And in 22:65

> "He withholds the sky from failing on the earth"

Doesn’t it mean that السماء means here the higher heavens ?

And that because Allah "raised the heavens" and is able to stop raising them, and that because the heavens are "raised up" then

If He wants to break the "pillars", which maybe are letting the heavens be stable and not in pieces, then the 6 or 7 other heavens can break in pieces, and because we are in the lowest heaven, and these heavens are above us, then Allah can send on us the heavens in pieces, or pieces of the heavens.

*You didn't understand my answer. I don't see why you wouldn't think that the 6 parallel universes can fall on the earth, because it is the only logical explanation that *fits* everything. You said "has to be held up" and that's exactly what's happening, look at my answer Surat Ar-Raad verse 2, they are held up by pillars we don't see. It's not atmosphere collapsing, but the heavens above us. Allah can break the pillars and because the heavens can't be stable without the pillars they will fall on us. This is probably how Allah means it. If you want science in this, then imagine the pillars are math and physics for the heavens above us, if God tries to stop gravity or quantum mechanics, then they will collapse. Maybe the pillars we don't see aren't actually pillars, but the science that let one be above the other without collapsing and falling. No one except God knows.*

Comment: i agree that would explain 34:9 and 26:187. However, i don't think it explains 22:65, because the universe or atmosphere is not something that needs to be held up. Idk. But i think the biggest issue that you didn't adress akhi is verse surah 17 verse 92. there it doesn't talk about pieces of the sky, but the sky IN pieces. so the atmosphere or universe ITSELF coming down piece by piece.

Comment: Here, I updated my answer, and I think it’s agreeing with 17:92 and 22:65. Just read it and try to understand it it’s a bit complex sorry.

Comment: I'm not sure it fits akhi. Because the verse says that the sky can fall on the earth. I don't think the 6 parallel universes can fall on the earth. I read an article that said that tve atmosphere would decimate us if it were to collapse, but the thing is that 22:65 is worded as if the sky is some roof that can fall on the earthand has to be held up. It doesn't really fit with "molecules above us collapsing".

Comment: Here, I edited my answer. Trust me, it does fit. This explanation is corresponding the most with the verses of the quran you mentioned.

Comment: So you mean like the universe collapsing in on itself kind of thing? Like a reverse big bang?

Comment: Not a reverse big bang, but yeah, the universe falling on the last heaven. I mean Allah withholds the universe with the pillars we don't see. And because the 7 or 6 heavens above us need the pillars that we don't see to be stable and not collapse into mere pieces, if the pillars are destroyed, then the heavens above us will collapse, and will fall into us in pieces. Because Allah controls the pillars, and He can destroy the pillars, then He is able to make the samaa fall on us into pieces. I know it's kind of difficult to imagine because we only see 1 universe.